# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin cors error with stripe

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, cors, stripe-payments

im trying to create a payment with stripe, this is my post request using express

```
try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      line_items: [
        {
          price: `${priceId}`, // Replace with the Price ID
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      // customer_email: {
      //   email,
      // },
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: `${process.env.SUCCESSURL}?success=true`, // if successful payment
      // cancel_url: `${process.env.FAILURL}?canceled=true`, // if payment is a failure
    });

    return res.redirect(303, session.url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error with payment checkout session: ", error);
  }
```

this is my frontend axios request

```
const checkout = () => {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:4000/api/payment/create-checkout-session",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const { data } = response;
      
        window.location = data.url;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I'm getting an error involving cors and the link to stripe

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_ (redirected from 'http://localhost:4000/api/payment/create-checkout-session') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

this is my cors conf

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // Replace with the origin of your frontend
  })
);
```

I'm getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. but I don't really understand what to do with that information or how to fix it

Comment: Your are using express; there is an npm module, [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors),  that does the job, without giving you thoughts

Comment: yes im using cors but its still not working

Comment: what is the cors script that would make it work?

Comment: Wait... My link points to a middleware, not to a script. But why you don't share your CORS conf?

Comment: this is all i have lol 

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  })
);
```

Comment: ive tried other things but none of them worked

Comment: Pay attention to your urls... You listen on 4000,  but CORS is for port 3000

Comment: yes isnt the origin supposed to listen on my frontend? my frontend is port 3000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254136/discussion-between-pierpy-and-evan-tech1234).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this problem, you can choose either of the following

- [Frontend] Instead of using XMLHttpRequest , use HTML form POST request to create a checkout session and redirect. You can refer to [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal?platform=billing#redirect) for example code
- [Backend] Instead of 303, return 200 together with the session URL. Process the response in your frontend and use JavaScript window.open(sessionUrl)to open the Billing Portal.